# How can I pass variable parameters into a Javascript Function using Excel VBA (2)

Tags: javascript, vba

Well based on the post: [The same as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032858/how-can-i-pass-variable-parameters-into-a-javascript-function-using-excel-vba)

I've tryed to do this:

```
Call mFramePesquisa.parentWindow.execScript("gotoPage(pesquisa.html?re_ligacao)", "JavaScript")
```

As you can see the js function takes one parameter "pesquisa.html?re_licagao" but when executed on the browser it gives an error saying that ":" was expected.

So i've tryed to quote the function parameter without success:

```
Call mFramePesquisa.parentWindow.execScript("gotoPage(" & chr(34) & "pesquisa.html?re_ligacao" & chr(34) & ")", "JavaScript")
```

or

```
Call mFramePesquisa.parentWindow.execScript("gotoPage('pesquisa.html?re_ligacao')", "JavaScript")
```

Both throw out an "Object expected" error on ie browser.

Any suggestions?

thx

PS: I've tried also to use chr(63) instead of "?" but without success.

**Edit:** I suspect it had something to do with the string used as parameter, since in the original JS the function is called like this on a onChange evento for a  object:

```
onchange=javascript:gotoPage(this.value)
```

Comment: `gotoPage('pesquisa.html?re_ligacao')` should work fine, but requires a function called `gotoPage` to be defined in the page. Try this instead: `"window.location.href = 'pesquisa.html?re_ligacao';"`

Comment: Yes, the gotoPage is defined on the document. And the window.location.href gives me the same error (":" was expected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me in a test page:

```
IE.document.parentWindow.execScript "RunMe(""hello"")", "jscript"
```

Tim

Comment: It worked!! Thanks! Anyway i've found that i was referencing the wrong document object since i'm working on a 5 level nested frame html document.