# How to pass JavaScript variable in ExcelVBA (Web Automation)

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

I'm currently doing some web automation. My recent problem is to pass content to tinymce text area with excel VBA.
After searching all over the internet, I think the possible answer can be found here: [How can I pass variable parameters into a Javascript Function using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032858/how-can-i-pass-variable-parameters-into-a-javascript-function-using-excel-vba).

However, I tried to do the same as mentioned in above link but failed.

```
IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript "tinyMCE.get('Server').setContent(" & inputStr & ")", "JavaScript"
```

Currently, the variable inputStr was declared in VBA as below:

```
With dataSheet
inputStr = .Range("B35").Value
End With
```

Does the variable need to be declared as javascript variable?
If so, how I can do that in excel VBA?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You would not declare as a javascript variable as it would be passed using VBA.

As it is a string variable you would do

```
Dim inputStr As String
```